# Flex crazy scroller with vgroup

Tags: apache-flex, scroll

In my flex mobile project I have a vgroup inside a scroller and I add element to the vgroup.
When I scroll (because only 5 elements fits the visible space) the scroller get crazy, and the new element that I add to the vgroup is not placed as last element. And my code doesn't work anymore. Is there a sort of virtual layout also for scrollers?

EDIT

This is the Scroller

```
<s:Scroller top="0" width="100%" bottom="100">
    <s:VGroup id="areaList" width="100%" gap="5">               
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

When I add an Area to the VGroup (Area is a SpriteVisualElement) is displayed after the previous area. But when I scroll and add a new area, the new one is not displayed in the last position of the VGroup as expected.

In the code i use the method `areaList.getElementAt(k)` to get the area at index k, but after the scroll it doesn't return the correct item.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it sounds like you need a DataGroup or List.  But, please share some code. Please quantify what "Crazy" means.  We're programmers, not Psychiatrist.  We can't fix Crazy

Comment: @Reboog711 We haven't created an app for that yet? We are slacking. Back on topic, this sounds more like what happens with `List`s than `VGroup`s, where `ItemRenderer`s are reused. If you run `VGroup.addElement()`, the item is added to the very end of the VGroup unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: I use the `.addElement()` method but after the scroll it doesn't work as expected, and the new item is not added to the very end of the group

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit is lacking clarification.  You need to provide more code and context.  Take this sentence: "When I add an Area to the VGroup is displayed after the previous area" it raises these questions: How do you add an area to the VGroup? What is displayed after the previous area?  What is the previous area?  I could ask three questions about every other new sentence in your question...

Comment: you are right... my english is not so good